# Remove Addin from SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

Recently I have installed an addin (Fulltext Manager) into my SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio. But it's not compatible with this version. This is the message I am getting

[image]

Its not removing after clicking on yes button.Its always showing this message when I am open SSMS 2008 R2.

So far I can't find any Addin Manager In SSMS 2008 R2. There is any option to remove this.?

Comment: -@SimpleCoder Read the question carefully I have mentioned that "It's not removing after clicking on Yes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually these add-ins will install a component in `Control Panel > Programs and Features` (or, depending on how old your operating system is, `Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs`. I'm fairly confident you'll find this add-in listed there, where you can perform a proper uninstall.